# PHP ldap_connect returns negative

Tags: php, ldap, ubuntu-18.04, windows-server-2016, dokuwiki

I stumbled across an issue while setting up LDAP for Dokuwiki using the authldap plugin. I run dokuwiki with php7.2 on Ubuntu 18.4 and have windows server 2016 as an active directory controller.

I have several services running that sucessfully use LDAP and i can use the tool "ldapsearch" to contact the Active directory host from the command line of the same machine that runs dokuwiki. Thus I assume that at least the connection should be alright.

So far I narrowed it down to the ldap_connect(server,port) method in the file /lib/plugins/authldap/auth.php

```
$this->con = @ldap_connect($server, $port);
```

This call returns -1 . An echo of **$server** and **$port** show the correct ip address and port.

I've run out of ideas how to debug this issue and would be very thankful for suggestions.

Thanks & greetings

**[Update]**
Upon suggestion I removed the silence flag. I could not find changes in any log giving further hints.

I have another log I havent properly looked at:

```
192.168.4.103 - - [06/Jan/2019:15:51:15 +0000] "POST /dokuwiki/doku.php?id=start&do=login&sectok= HTTP/1.0" 403 11344 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
192.168.4.103 - - [06/Jan/2019:15:51:15 +0000] "GET /dokuwiki/lib/exe/indexer.php?id=start&1546789875 HTTP/1.0" 200 42 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
```

For me this looks like there was a sucessful request (http code 200), followed by a 403, suggesting that this action was forbidden.

I assume this is a default answer due to the failed ldap_connect

Comment: First thing first, remove the `@` operator (also known as the "stfu operator") to see any error message that may be thrown out of ldap_connect(). See [Error Control Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)

Comment: what's the port you are using? As ldap_connect does not actually connect (as the docs clearly state) but only checks whether the given information "looks" valid it's interesting that it should. return -1 as it either returns a resource or FALSE. I suspect an issue with LDAPS but can't say more without a bit more detail. What's contained in the $host and $port variable?

Comment: port is 389 and host is the ip address of the domain controller. I verified those values using ldapsearch from the same machine.